# Techniques to Eliminate Duplicate Matching Logic in F#

Tags: f#

When designing union type hierarchies, there seems to be potential for a considerable amount of logic duplication. For a simple and somewhat contrived example, consider the following type that represents a "flexible" number:

```
type Number =
    |Integer of int
    |Real of float

static member (+) (x : Number, y:Number) =
    match x,y with
    |Integer(x), Integer(y) -> Integer(x + y)
    |Integer(x), Real(y) -> Real(float x + y)
    |Real(x), Integer(y) -> Real(x + float y)
    |Real(x), Real(y) -> Real(x + y)

static member (-) (x : Number, y:Number) =
    match x,y with
    |Integer(x), Integer(y) -> Integer(x - y)
    |Integer(x), Real(y) -> Real(float x - y)
    |Real(x), Integer(y) -> Real(x - float y)
    |Real(x), Real(y) -> Real(x - y)
```

Additional operators will contain similarly repetitive matching logic. Is there a pattern/practice that can be applied to consolidate the logic in one function to eliminate such redundancy?

(Note: I realize that there are better ways of dealing with generic arithmetic in F#; this example should be considered just as an illustration of the general "how do I stop repeating myself?" problem in the context of pattern matching)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could abstract over `(+)` and `(-)` by writing one function that takes the integer and floating arithmetic operators as arguments:

```
static member binOp (intOp : int -> int -> int) (floatOp : float -> float -> float) (x : Number, y:Number) =
    match x,y with
    |Integer(x), Integer(y) -> Integer(intOp x y)
    |Integer(x), Real(y) -> Real(floatOp (float x) y)
    |Real(x), Integer(y) -> Real(floatOp x (float y))
    |Real(x), Real(y) -> Real(floatOp x y)

static member (+) (x,y) = Number.binOp (+) (+) (x,y)
static member (-) (x,y) = Number.binOp (-) (-) (x,y)
```

The same function should work fine for `(*)` as well. But when you get to `(/)` the pattern starts to break down because you probably want a floating point result even for integer inputs.

In my experience it's often simpler just to live with the duplication - it's usually not that bad in practice and trying to abstract too much leads to unreadable code.

In some cases where individual pattern-match cases get quite complex, [active patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233248.aspx) can help you abstract the pattern once. I don't think they make sense in your specific example but they're worth keeping in mind.

Comment: Minor hack when bind to the same variables: `| Integer(i), Real(r) | Real(r), Integer(i) -> Real(floatOp (float i) r)`

Comment: That would only work for commutative operators like `(+)`, not `(-)`